# Can't connect anything except monitors to Dell Thunderbolt 3 TB16 dock station

Tags: 16.04, usb, dell, thunderbolt, dockstation

I am connecting my Dell XPS notebook to Thunderbolt 3 TB16 docking station. Notebooks is running under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Docking station can connect with Ethernet, USB (mouse an keyboard) and monitors (HDMI and Type-C).

Unfortunately, nothing works except monitors.

Is it possible to configure thunderbolt under Ubuntu 16?